# Get the output using select sum case when

Tags: php

I am trying to display output in below format :

[image]

**Error** :

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **') as minrange, sum(case when DATE(holddate) = CURDATE()) as holddate, sum(case' at**

**code :**

```
<?php

$sql =

"select 
sum(case when DATE(reattemptdate) = CURDATE()) as minrange,
sum(case when DATE(holddate) = CURDATE()) as holddate,
sum(case when DATE(reattemptdate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as prev_reattemptdate,
sum(case when DATE(holddate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as prev_holddate
from orders
 ";
$results = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sql); 
$numrowsresult =$results[0]['count'];  
echo $numrowsresult;

?>
```

Comment: Read about MySQL [`CASE` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

Comment: What's the purpose of the query? Your `CASE` expressions do not produce any value. The aliases of the expressions (`as holddate`, `as prev_reattemptdate`) suggest they are dates but adding dates (`sum(...) as holddate`) doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @axiac Thanks for suggestion, basically i am trying to get count.... means in that `holddate` means there are 52 `hold` values in `holddate` column `yesterday`..... there are `40` values `today`.... like that.....

Comment: @axiac than how i can get values[count] of those aliases in php (as `holddate`, as `prev_reattemptdate`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CASE WHEN but you never specify the THEN (and ELSE).

Therefore the syntax is missing something.

Comment: thanks, this fixed the issue :  `select sum(case when DATE(reattemptdate) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reattemptdate,
       sum(case when DATE(holddate) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as holddate,
       sum(case when DATE(reattemptdate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as prev_reattemptdate,
       sum(case when DATE(holddate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as prev_holddate
from orders`

Comment: @vickeycolors you can put the fixed query as your own answer (and even accept it if you think it's the best answer).

Answer (score 1):

I needed this : `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

```
select sum(case when DATE(reattemptdate) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reattemptdate,
       sum(case when DATE(holddate) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as holddate,
       sum(case when DATE(reattemptdate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as prev_reattemptdate,
       sum(case when DATE(holddate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as prev_holddate
from orders;
```